# Which non-mathematical subject could I tutor to make the most money?

Tags: small-business, sole-proprietorship

Assuming I can learn whatever and I have respected teaching credentials

I'm thinking LSAT, but perhaps the subject with the highest ceiling would be prepping high schoolers of the ultra-wealthy? I'm not sure. Perhaps Stack Exchange knows.

Comment: I would guess that the largest market would be SAT preparation and it would be the easiest material to learn as compared to the much smaller sample of LSAT, DAT and MCAT aspirants.

Comment: This question is not about personal finance.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic “Strategies for earning more money”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked as a private tutor for virtually all math, physics, and chemistry subjects, as well as a tutor for all major standardized entrance tests.  My personal experience was that of the non-mathematical subjects, MCAT tutoring was the highest breadwinner.  However, this took place in a town with a major university and a medical school.

I agree that prepping high schoolers of the ultra-wealthy is a major breadwinner as well, and may even out-compete MCAT tutoring depending on where you are at.  However, your proximity to a neighborhood full of wealthy families (and the size of that neighborhood) plays a very large role in determining how much a tutor would earn.  Furthermore, most of the ultra-wealthy parents are usually only willing to pay top-dollar for someone who is or was a high school teacher of the exact subject you're tutoring, or has a similar credential to back it up.

On a related note, I should add that although I've met some tutors who made quite a bit of money given the circumstances, most tutors do not consider their work to be a sustainable income.